# What are the implications of each way to make an array of objects without std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, arduino

I'm writing code for Arduinos, so I have never used `std::vector`, because Arduinos do not support it.

I'm going for a section-wise customizable LED strip, each section is supposed to be represented by its own object. A fixed max amount of sections is fine, so I don't need a dynamically sized array.

---

As far as I understand, I have three options to implement this. To demonstrate, I'm using this class:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    int var = 0;

public:
    Test () {}

    Test(int input) {
        var = input;
    }

    ~Test() {
        cout << "Instance with var = " << var << " deleted" << endl;
    }

    void printTest() {
        cout << "var = " << var << endl;
    }
};
```

Option 1: Array of pointers populated with `new`.

```
int main() {
    int maxTest = 10;
    Test* test[maxTest];

    test[0] = new Test(10);
    test[0]->printTest();
    delete test[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
var = 10
Instance with var = 10 deleted
```

This seems to be the 'standard' way that most people recommend, however I don't like that I can't use `delete[]` but have to delete each instance individually. This is especially annoying, because trying to `delete` an object that is not yet initialized will crash the program (at least for me, no error/exception, execution just stops). So I can't just say `for(int i; i<maxTest; i++) delete test[i];` but have to track the number and position of each object separately, because when `test[0]` through `test[2]` are populated I still need to be able to delete `test[1]`.

---

Option 2: Initializing the array with `new`.

```
int main() {
    int maxTest = 10;
    Test* test = new Test[maxTest];

    test[0] = Test(10);
    test[0].printTest();
    delete[] test;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Instance with var = 10 deleted
var = 10
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 10 deleted
```

I've seen this option a lot too, however here, instantiating a specific object (like `test[0] = Test(10);`) apparently causes the destructor to be called first. This makes some sense to me as I imagine the instance sitting at `test[0]` from initializing the array needs to be deleted first, but why does this instance's `var` equal 10 instead of 0 (see first line of output)?
I can't really use this without working around the destructor being called at times when I don't want it to be called which I would like to avoid. Also it feels inefficient to have `maxTest` instances active no matter how few I actually want to use.

---

Option 3: Ditching pointers altogether, same problem as option 2 and feels wrong.

```
int main() {
    int maxTest = 10;
    Test test[maxTest];

    test[0] = Test(10);
    test[0].printTest();

    return 0;
}
```

Output same as Option 2.

The mentioned problem aside, I am wondering why I don't see this suggested anywhere, maybe someone can explain? As long as sufficient memory is available to just keep the data in the stack (which in a closed system like an Arduino should be possible to know) there is nothing wrong with this, right?

---

Am I missing another useful way of implementation? How would you achieve this and why? Appreciate any and all input! Cheers

Comment: Real Arduinos do not support <iostream> without extra effort, neither.

Comment: option 3 is the right option if not using std::vector

Comment: Option 4 (arduino style): Use a global array of objects. (Do not care about deletion)

Comment: @datafiddler Ty for the heads up, but <iostream> will not be used on the controller, it's just for this example.

Comment: @Juraj Thank you! Any input regarding the problem I described?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, C++ officially has no support for Variable Length Arrays! They are an optional C feature (since C11) which has never been integrated in C++ because it is a nightmare for destructors and exception handling.

This is legal C++:

```
...
int main() {
    constexpr int maxTest = 10;
    Test test[maxTest] = {Test(10)};

    test[0].printTest();

    return 0;
}
```

And it give as expected:

```
var = 10
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 0 deleted
Instance with var = 10 deleted
```

Because you now define a true automatic array, provide a custom initialization for its first element, and have the compiler to default initialize the other elements.

And the compiler gently deletes the array and its elements when the array goes out of scope. But of course all the elements of the array are initialized at startup and destroyed when the program ends, no matter how many you really want to use...

If you really want to be able to use a variable number of objects, only create them when required, and then get rid of all of them in a single operation, you have to use a vector. If `std::vector` is not available on Arduino, you could provide your own implementation. You need:

- an allocated array of pointers
- the current number of elements in the array
- a function to construct a new element at the end of the array
- a destructor that will first destruct its existing elements
- deleted copy/move constructors and assignment operators if you do not need them (rule of five)
- optionaly a method to remove the last element

Probably simpler and much more robust than trying to play with Variable Length Arrays of non trivial data...